# ASP.NET Which HTML editor can do everything I want?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, editor

I have tried to use the standard AJAX HTMLeditor from here (http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) and I have try to work with the FCKEditor (from http://ckeditor.com/)

But both don't do everything. I call the AJAX standard control A and the FCKeditor F.

With the A editor it is impossible to get your HTML text in the HTML content. You can only get it in the Design content. (this next code doesn't do the job: string htmlContentStr = Editor1.Content).

With F it is possible to get it in the HTML content (it does this by default), but to get your changes back in HTML is impossible. (this next code doesn't do the job: string htmlContentStr = FCKeditor1.Value).

So what I need is a HTML editor that is possible to put HTML text in HTML content, a user can make changes in the designcontent and after the changes 're make it must be possible to get the HTMLcontent and put it away in a string or database.

Is this possible or do I need a commercial one to get this feature?

If my question isn't clear, please let me know.

Thnx

Comment: I'm not sure what you want or where or why.  I presume you want to allow user input into a page (why else use FCKeditor?).  But I am not certain and I think you need to be much more specific.  As in saying what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I mean is this: I have HTML code in the database, when I try to set this in the HTML content of editor A then this is impossible.

Comment: So this code: a.Content = databaseHTML;

Comment: Doesn't work. (Sorry for this manner of reacting, but I can't use a enter here ;-) )

Comment: In editor F it's the otherway around, you can't get the html content: if you use this code: string databaseHTML = F.Value;                      So what do you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [XStandard](http://www.xstandard.com/) quite easily and it let me manipulate the HTML. I didn't bother using it as a control, but just read and wrote (escaped) the HTML where needed into the asp output.